# Would changing the permissions implemented by a module require a new version of the module?

Tags: 7

I have created a module, and I have to change the permissions implemented (and used) from the module. Should I create a new major version (e.g. passing from 7.x-1 to 7.x-2), or is it fine to create a minor version (e.g. passing from 7.x-1.3 to 7.x-1.4)?

I am talking of a module for which there is already an official release, not of a module that has only a development snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it changes significant behaviour from previous version I recommend changing the major version. Even if its just a single adjustment like permissions. Wrong or missing permissions may cause huge problems on a site running your module.

Comment: I accepted this answer because user permissions are normally associated to routes, or to actions a user can take; introducing a new permission, or even using an existing permission instead of a new one previously used means to significantly change the module behavior. Often, new permissions mean new code added to the module, which could also mean a significant behavior change is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I personally dont think that there should be a new branch for this altogether, or is required.
We can very well get away with releasing an updated version of it, however if any Db changes are required, we will have to incorporate those as well.